# Which is better for read and removing a whole collection in java, iter.remove() or collection.clear()?

Tags: java, performance

Compare

```
    synchronized (countList) {
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Entry<Long, Long> entry = iter.next();
            if(entry.getVaue>0)
                 entry.output();
        }
        countList.clear();
    }
```

with

```
    synchronized (countList) {
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Entry<Long, Long> entry = iter.next();
            if(entry.getVaue>0)
                 entry.output();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

Is there a real difference? I am guessing that maybe garbage collection is better for the `collection.clear` method.

Comment: Why not benchmark it and see?

Comment: @Andrew, faster, considering syncronization.

Comment: What's the concrete type of your collection?

Comment: Did you miss out where you get the iterator from the collection, inside the `synchronized` block?

Comment: BTW: You might want to look at the formatting of your code. Tabs, bad. Braces, good.

Comment: @Hawtin, why are tabs bad? You mean the if(entry.getVaue>0) entry.output();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are situations where `N` `remove()`s through the iterator would yield `O(N log N)`, or even worse, `O(N^2)` performance (e.g. on an `ArrayList`). I can't think of any scenario where `clear()` would perform as badly.

I would say that `clear()` is probably better. It's done as one operation, so implementations can optimize it better since it's not an incremental modification to the collection that `remove()` is (where invariants need to be maintained, etc).

Also, collection iterators must guard against `IllegalStateException` and/or `ConcurrentModificationException`. With `N` `remove()`s, that's `N` checks, which can add up. Finally, as a reminder, not all iterators support `remove()`.

Think of it this way:

- N `remove()` operations are done through a middleman (the iterator), and it puts the collection into `N` different states before it becomes empty
- 1 `clear()` is a direct operation on the collection, and it's only 1 state transition

Comment: Pretty much by definition clear will *always* be at least as good, and with *very* few exceptions, orders of magnitude better.

Answer (score 0):

I presume iter.remove is called for every entry, right? It is better(performance degradation when removing one by one - it depends on the collection implementation how much slower) to invoke clear at the end or just let the collection to be garbage collected.

```
synchronized (countList) {
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Long, Long> entry = iter.next();
        if(entry.getVaue>0) {
             entry.output();
        }
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why comment that clear() is better, and then provide an example which uses remove()?

Comment: See polygenelubricants's response